# Python - threading - how do I create a playlist function to run in the background with threading?

Tags: python, multithreading, arraylist, pygame

Im currently trying to make a playlist function to run in the background of my code. I am using threading and pygame, and the playlist is an array list. I keep getting this error:

```
Exception in thread Thread-4:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\harry\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\threading.py", line 932, in 
_bootstrap_inner

    self.run()
  File "C:\Users\harry\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\threading.py", line 870, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

this is the related snippet of code:

```
from threading import Thread
from time import sleep

def playPlaylist(playlist):
    mixer.init()
    for music in playlist:
        mixer.music.load(music)
        mixer.music.play()
        while mixer.music.get_busy():
            sleep(1)

Thread(target=playPlaylist, args=(playlist)).start()
```

Github repository: https://github.com/M1st3rMinecraft/python-virtual-assistant

Answer (score 0):

Try changing `Thread(target=playPlaylist, args=(playlist)).start()` to `Thread(target=playPlaylist, args=(playlist, )).start()` it helped in my case. And also check all of the elements in your code in which you are calling functions if they are not strings. If that didn't work share your file with the mixer class so I can help you further.

Comment: where would I find them 2 files please?

Comment: Sorry, I thought you are using django. Please share the code of the mixer class.

Comment: I have used the mixer else where in my script and that works fine so I would have thought it would be the threading?

Comment: I think that this error is not caused by the threading. Without the rest of the code it's hard to tell more.

Comment: here's the github I just made for the project if it helps: https://github.com/M1st3rMinecraft/python-virtual-assistant

Answer (score 0):

The `args` parameter is supposed to be an `iterable` (such as a tuple or list) where each element becomes an argument to the function `playPlayList`. When you specify `args=(playlist)`, the parentheses surrounding `playlist` does not denote a tuple of one element. For that you would need to specify `args=(playlist,)`. Therefore, the `playlist` itself is being interpreted as the iterable and each element of it will be considered a separate argument to `playPlayList`. There must be only currently one element in `playlist` for if there were, for example, 3, you would get an error message such as:

```
TypeError: playPlaylist() takes 1 positional argument but 3 were given
```

So you need to specify: `args=(playlist,)`. That's problem number one.

Since you are not being passed `playlist` any more but rather the first and only element of that list as the argument, that is probably leading to the second error. But I would think you would get the exception at:

```
for music in playlist:
```

But perhaps the first element of `playlist` is itself iterable. Try fixing the first problem, though, and see what happens.

Comment: I have just tried this and it gave me the same error. I tried the first fix with and without a space after the comma.

Comment: Space? What is significant is the comma following playlist in `args=(playlist,)`

Comment: Another person had suggested the same but with a space

Comment: That was a spacey suggestion. But seriously, I think you took the space to seriously; it would have no significance in this context. When you pass the correct argument list, do you get a new exception or its' really the same *exact* exception? Are you including the complete stack trace so we can tell which statement in the code you have show is throwing the exception?

Comment: yes after I put a comma after playlist I got the same error and I put the whole error in my first post and didn't leave anything out.